# escaping matching quotes except tag's properties

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I want to escape matching quotes except those in tag properties, for example:

input:

```
xyz <test foo='123 abc' bar="def 456"> f00 'escape me' b4r "me too" but not this </tEsT> blah 'escape " me'
```

expected output:

```
xyz <test foo='123 abc' bar="def 456"> f00 \'escape me\' b4r \"me too\" but not this </tEsT> blah \'escape " me\'
```

I have following regexp:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(([\'"])((\\\2|.)*?)\2)/', "\\\\$2$3\\\\$2", $input);
```

which returns:

```
xyz <test foo=\'123 abc\' bar=\"def 456\"> f00 \'escape me\' b4r \"me too\" but not this </tEsT> blah \'escape " me\'
```

now I would like to use regexp zero-width negative look behind to skip matching quotes that have equal sign in front:

```
$result = preg_replace('/((?<=[^=])([\'"])((\\\2|.)*?)\2)/', "\\\\$2$3\\\\$2", $input);
```

but the result is still not as expected:

```
xyz <test foo='123 abc\' bar="def 456"> f00 \'escape me\' b4r "me too" but not this </tEsT> blah \'escape " me'
```

Can you please give me advice how I can skip whole unwanted block (="blah blah blah") instead of skipping just first quote?

Comment: Do not do this with regular expressions. You will regret it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking backward to establish the context, look forward.  It's usually much easier.

```
$result = preg_replace('/([\'"])(?![^<>]*>)((?:(?!\1).)*)\1/',
                       '\\\\$1$2\\\\$1',
                        $subject);
```

```
(['"])            # capture the open quote
(?![^<>]*>)       # make sure it's not inside a tag
(                 # capture everything up to the next quote
  (?:             # ...after testing each character to
    (?!\1|[<>]).  # ...to be sure it's not the opening quote
  )*              # ...or an angle bracket
)
\1                # match another quote of the same type as the first one
```

I'm assuming there won't be any angle brackets in the attribute values.

Comment: it works perfectly for me! thank you for detailed explanation :) where did you learned regular expressions that well?

Comment: @Artur: mainly from reading [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do), practice, and hanging out in forums like this. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one.

```
$str = "xyz <test foo='123 abc' bar=\"def 456\"> f00 'escape me' b4r \"me too\" but not this <br/> <br/></tEsT> blah 'escape \" me'";

$str_escaped = preg_replace_callback('/(?<!\<)[^<>]+(?![^<]*\>)/','escape_quotes',$str);
// check all the strings outside every possible tag
// and replace each by the return value of the function below

function escape_quotes($str) {
    if (is_array($str)) $str = $str[0];
    return preg_replace('/(?<!\\\)(\'|")/','\\\$1',$str);
    // escape all the non-escaped single and double quotes
    // and return the escaped block
}
```

Comment: Can someone please verify if this is working in every condition? I'm assuming all the **<** and **>** signs are escaped (into `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively) other than the ones surrounding tags.